# animatable is continuously making the view to grow

Tags: react-native, react-animations

I used Animatable plugin to add some animations to my app components.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
     <Animatable.View
        animation="tada"
        duration="1500"
        iterationCount={0}
        style={styles.logo}>
          <Logo />
     </Animatable.View>
</View>
```

But i found that `animation="tada"` is making the component growing continuosly as below.
except `Flippers` animation none of the animations are stopping from growing.

How to solve this ?

[image]

Comment: dont you want iterationCount={1} to run once?

Comment: @EricHasselbring i tried that for login component and is still the same. in above example i pasted only logo component. i tried all different values and even removed that and tried.

Comment: when you use iterationCount={1} do you get any errors? there are 2 errors in your screenshot

Comment: @EricHasselbring where is the error

Comment: its in the banner at the bottom "Failed prop type", prolly says that for the duration too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem because I did the same mistake in past.

```
duration="1500"
```

should be changed to

```
duration={1500}
```